# Fuzzy rule implementation

Tags: references, fuzzy, variational-inference

I have a rudimentary understanding of fuzzy inference rules of the form IF(x is A) THEN(y is "LOW"). I have not been able to find examples of fuzzy rules that cause a change in the output variable; e.g. IF(z is C) Then(y is "INCREASED_MODERATELY"). In these expressions, all of the variables/concepts are linguistic vars with fuzzy values; e.g. INCREASED_MODERATELY might be a representation of an expert's opinion that y should be increased by "about 50%" when z is C.
I have seen similar statements in Earl Cox's Fuzzy Systems textbook, but I have not been able to find how rules that imply a change are implemented in Fuzzy Logic.
Would someone please point me towards citations that explain how such a fuzzy variation rule is implemented?

Comment: I have found Generating fuzzy rules by learning from examples by Wang and Mendel interesting.